# Find directories that are older than 60 days by name

Tags: bash, unix, directory, find

I have a directory with some files and subdirectories. In that directory I need to find files by name pattern ".cm-2015.10.10" that are older than 30 days. This command finds me the needed directories:

```
find comdit/ -type d -name .cm-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9] -print
```

but how can I specify that I only need folders older than 60 days? Adding -ctime +60 did nothing for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `-mtime` which you are looking for:

```
find comdit/ -type d -mtime +30 -name .cm-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9] -print
```

Here are the docs:

```
   -atime n
          File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When  find  figures  out
          how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, any
          fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
          have been accessed at least two days ago.

   -ctime n
          File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
          of file status change times.

   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
          of file modification times.
```